# Nestjs problem creating mysql table from entity

Tags: nest, nestjs, typeorm

I'm having a problem when I change an entity file and Nest/TypeOrm regenerates the mysql table. It doesn't reflect what I have in the entity file

this is my **user.entity.ts**

```
import { BaseEntity, Entity, Column, Unique, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
@Unique(['id'])
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  uid: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  surname: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  skype: string;

  @Column()
  levelClassDone: boolean;

  @Column({default: 1, nullable: true})
  userType: number;
}
```

this is the description of the created table in mysql:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| surname        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| email          | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| uid            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| skype          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| levelClassDone | tinyint      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| userType       | int          | YES  |     | 1       |       |
| id             | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**id** is not *numeric* and neither *auto_increment*

Seems like it's caching old user.entity.ts versions where I had different field specifications. I tried to drop the table and also drop the whole database.

Comment: Please check your ORM config: you might be using some "old compiled" file. The property `entities` is really important, this must match your target entity files, and **only** these files (not copies, or old/compiled .js files).
You could also try to enable both "dropSchema"  and "synchronize", in order to ensure that every single try is made with a fresh schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try provide the `autoLoadEntities` and `synchronize` options to TypeORM when importing it to your module:

```js
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
      ...
    }
```

Comment: I have **synchronize: true** set but **autoLoadEntities** is not recognized as option. I have tried different options, like **cache: false**

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
```